# How can we determine the measure in a specific interval?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, symmetric-matrices, gaussian-integral

If we want to integrate the following:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\log(5 + 4 \cos(x))\,d\mu(x).$$

How can we determine the measure in a specific interval? and how can we know if the measure is symmetric or non-symmetric?

For example:

the measure $d\mu(x)= \dfrac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}\,d(e^{(x)})$ on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is non-symmetric.

Comment: What's that supposed to mean? You (well, maybe not *you*) can calculate the integral if the measure is given, but you certainly can't determine the measure from the integral, not even the symmetry.

Comment: I know some types of the measure are given in a certain interval. for example, Jacobi measure on [-1,1]. I was thinking if we can generalized it and define it in any given interval.